# How do i append to the Maya PYTHONPATH?

Tags: python, maya

I am working through Practical Maya Programming, and trying to set a 'development root' on my PC, I have followed the instructions (below) exactly but it is not working - At the point where I type 'mayapy.exe' I get the warning "'mayapy.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

**From the book:**

Let's decide where we will do our coding. We'll call this location the development root for the rest of the book. To be concise, I'll choose C:\mayapybook\pylib to house all of our Python code.

Create the development root folder, and inside of it create an empty file named minspect.py.

Now, we need to get C:\mayapybook\pylib onto Python's sys.path so it can be imported. The easiest way to do this is to use the PYTHONPATH environment variable. From a Windows command line you can run the following to add the path, and ensure it worked:

```
> set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\mayapybook\pylib
> mayapy.exe
>>> import sys
>>> 'C:\\mayapybook\\pylib' in sys.path
True
>>> import minspect
>>> minspect
<module 'minspect' from '...\minspect.py'>
```

**EDIT**

This is how it is working for me at the moment:

```
PS C:\Users\Me> set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\mayapybook\pylib
C:\mayapybook\pylib : The term 'C:\mayapybook\pylib' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file,
or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and
try again.
At line:1 char:29
+ set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\mayapybook\pylib
+                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\mayapybook\pylib:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

So the code from the book is not working but the code from the post by DrHaze seems to:

```
PS C:\Users\Me> setx PATH "%PATH%C:\mayapybook\pylib\"

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
```

But when I run the Maya Python Interpreter and check if C:\mayapybook\pylib\ is in sys path it returns false:

```
>>> 'C:\\mayapybook\\pylib' in sys.path
False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Powershell, there are different commands and strategies for managing environment variables.

1. You can set a variable permanently with `SetEnvironmentVariable`
2. You can set for the current shell session with: `$env:VARNAME =
   VARVALUE`
3. You can put the commands to set variables in a powershell profile
   file.

I would go with the third option. All three are detailed below:

**Option 1. To append the directory "C:\mayapybook\pylib\" to the existing
    PYTHONPATH permanently for your account:**

```
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PYTHONPATH", $env:PYTHONPATH +";C:\mayapybook\pylib\", "User")
```

**Option 2. To append the Maya bin folder to your PATH for only the current
    shell session:**

```
$env:PATH += ";C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\bin\"
```

**Option 3. Create a powershell profile and set your env vars there.**

First you'll need to make sure powershell scripts can run locally: 
Hit the windows button, start typing powershell, right click and open as administrator. Enter:
    Get-ExecutionPolicy

If it is says Restricted or AllSigned, set it to RemoteSigned like so:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

Close that shell. Now in another powershell (not admin) type:

```
cd ~\Documents
md WindowsPowerShell
cd WindowsPowerShell
New-Item -path "profile.ps1" -type file
notepad.exe profile.ps1
```

Paste into the file any commands you want to run whenever a new powershell is opened:

```
Write-Host "Hello From Your Profile"
$env:PATH += ";C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2016\bin\"
$env:PYTHONPATH += ";C:\mayapybook\pylib\"
```

Now whenever you open a powershell, you'll get a silly message and those paths will be set. You can test by typing:

```
Write-Host $env:PATH
```

or to list all env vars:

```
Get-ChildItem Env:
```

You should now be able to run commands from the maya bin directory. For example, type: maya to start maya.

Some other useful powershell env var commands [here](http://xahlee.info/powershell/environment_variables.html).

Answer (score 4):

This error `"'mayapy.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."` means that the path where mayapy.exe is located is not included in the `PATH` environment variable. Your system tries to look in all the folders included in the `PATH` variable but can't find an executable called `mayapy.exe`.

The executable `mayapy.exe` is generally located here:

`C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya(VERSION)\bin\mayapy.exe`
on my computer it's located here: `C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\bin\mayapy.exe`

To add the `mayapy.exe` location to your path, use one of the following commands:

- `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\bin\"` if you
  want to change it permanently
- `set PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\bin\"` only works for the current instance of the cmd session.

---

### EDIT

The error you show in your edit is the source of the problem. Windows failed to set the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`. Hence, when you execute `'C:\\mayapybook\\pylib' in sys.path` it returns `False`. `sys.path` is in fact containing the value of `PYTHONPATH`. That's why it returns `False`.

### Now, why did it fail to set this environment variable?

First I can see that you are using `Windows Powershell`, keep this in mind.

**The command I gave you is:**

`set PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\bin\"`

**You wrote:**

`set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\mayapybook\pylib`

**What it should be:**

`set PYTHONPATH "%PYTHONPATH%;C:\mayapybook\pylib\"`

The syntax is a bit different and this last command should work.

As an explaination, your book gives you some commands to type in the vintage/old-style windows terminal: `cmd.exe`
As you are using `Windows Powershell`, some commands might have a different syntax.
Now what you can do is:

- Use `cmd.exe` (Right click on the title bar -> Properties to custom it)
- Use `Powershell` but keep in mind that the syntax might be a bit different than in your book

Comment: Thanks @DrHaze for this - though your answer hasn't exactly solved my problem.. I have now set my path to C\mayapybook\pylib\ using your setx code above as a template (it returned 'SUCCESS: specified value saved'), then I executed mayapy.exe, and now in the newly loaded python interpreter it is still returning false to 'C:\\mayapybook\\pylib' in sys.path

Comment: Hi, I just edited my answer. Don't hesitate to give another shout if you face any troubles.

Comment: Thanks! Sounds promising.. Will try it out later